# How to find the eigen vector of a system that does not have similar equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I am trying to solve for an eigenvector provided
my matrix
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 7 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

eigenvalues are $9$ and $-5$

How can I get an eigenvector when I set lambda to $-5$?

$$
\begin{array}{cc|c}
 -3 & 7&0 \\
 7 & -3&0 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: You may be tricking yourself into thinking this is a complicated question because it involves more advanced concepts such as eigenvectors and eigenvalues which you were not introduced to until a later chapter.  That is incorrect.  This is exactly the same problem you should have been introduced to in the first chapter or two... just solve for the nullspace (*kernel*) of the corresponding matrix.

Comment: That said, you appear to have made an arithmetic mistake.  $2-(-5)=7$, not $-3$.  The matrix you should have arrived at after $A-(-5)I$ is $\begin{bmatrix}7&7\\7&7\end{bmatrix}$.  Recall the definitions of eigenvalues and eigenvectors... a nonzero vector $v$ is an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$ iff $Av=\lambda v$.  By rearranging, that is $Av-\lambda v = 0$ and $(A-\lambda I)v = 0$ and so $v$ is in the nullspace of $(A-\lambda I)$.  You added instead of subtracting or made an arithmetic error, not handling the sign properly.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 7 \\
 7 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)-(-5)I=(0,0)$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 7 & 7 \\
 7 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\
 y \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$7x+7y=0\to y=-x$ so eigenvector is $(1,-1)$

In a similar way for the other eigenvalue you get $(1,1)$